# Living with rust lifetime

Tags: pointers, rust, lifetime

I'm actually trying to write a simple command-line program in rust. It should look for command line arguments and if there are no, it should ask the user to enter the required argument. Here is my code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let args = os::args();
    let mut input: &str;
    if args.len() < 2 {
        println!("Please enter a number:");
        input = reader.read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line").as_slice().trim();
    } else {
        input = args.get(1).as_slice();
    }

    let opt: Option<int> = from_str(input);
    let num: int = match opt{
        Some(number) => number,
        None         => 1
    };
}
```

I understand that the result of read_line() has only the lifetime of the block which invokes it, and therefor the program does not compile. But I don't see any other way to handle this.

Rust is my first system programming language, and I think I still didn't really get the idea of pointers, especially of the difference between `~` and `&`, so maybe there is a solution using pointers, which I don't see because of my lack of understanding of pointers.

Thanks for your help!

Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm also a newbie, played with Rust for only two weeks so far...

### Use another `String` buffer

You can effectively extend the lifetime of your short-lived `String` by moving it to another `mut String` with a longer lifetime:

```
use std::{io, os};

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let args = os::args();
    let mut save : String;
    let input: &str = if args.len() < 2 {
        println!("Please enter a number:");
        save = reader.read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line");
        save.as_slice().trim()
    } else {
        args[1].as_slice()
    };

    let opt: Option<int> = from_str(input);
    let num: int = match opt{
        Some(number) => number,
        None         => 1
    };
    println!("num=={}", num);
}
```

This is a bit ugly but the most memory-efficient (who cares...??)

### Just use `String` everywhere

As proposed by @Levans

```
use std::{io, os};

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let args = os::args();
    let input: String = if args.len() < 2 {
        println!("Please enter a number:");
        String::from_str(reader.read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line").as_slice().trim())
    } else {
        args[1].clone()
    };

    let opt: Option<int> = from_str(input.as_slice());
    let num: int = match opt{
        Some(number) => number,
        None         => 1
    };
    println!("num=={}", num);
}
```

I felt `args[1].clone()` was a bit counterintuitive, when `args[1]` was of type `String`.  But otherwise we would end up with moving a `String` out of the immutable `String` vector `args`.

### Note on `.ok().expect(...)`

You may find the `unwrap()` method convenient for small programs

- http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/type.Result.html#method.unwrap

Comment: Thank you for showing some syntatic sugar using if and making me think  & learn about what my ok().expect(...) code actually did. I copy&pasted it from some site without understanding, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, the problem comes from the fact that what you store in `input` is a `&str`, that is to say, a slice to a string.

In Rust, a slice is a view to the content of something (an array, a vector, a string...) in an array like fashion, and is in fact a reference to the first element aware of the length of the data, but it doesn't own anything.

You are true when you understand the underlying `String` is destroyed at the end of the block, and after this is done, your `input` would refer to memory that as been freed, which is not allowed by Rust. You need to need a copy of the data, because you can't take ownership of it given the processing you do to it.

You can have your `input` be of type `String` rather than `&str`, this way it will own its data. You'll need to make some changes like :

```
input = String::from_str(/* your old code */);
```

and

```
let opt: Option<int> = from_str(input.as_slice());
```